# Como instalar uma NuGet HIDsharp no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, nuget

Preciso fazer a comunicação entre um **WPF** que estou criando e uma porta **USB** que recebe dados de um hardware. Lendo sobre, vi que é necessário uma biblioteca chamada **HIDSharp** que seria um **NuGet** para fazer essa comunicação, porém não sei bem o que é um **NuGet** e nem como instalá-lo. Encontrei um *.sln* demo no *GitHub*.
Essa solução vem com dois **.cs** `Program.cs` e `HIDInterface.cs`.
Gostaria de saber se alguém já fez esse tipo de comunicação e como faço para instalar isso dentro do meu projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Visual Studio se vai em Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution, na nova janela você pode ir em browse e pesquisar a biblioteca **HIDSharp**

ou

Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console e colocar **Install-Package HidSharp -Version 1.5.0**.

Com isso ele irá instalar a biblioteca no seu projeto.