# Erro ao tentar usar classe/método de uma biblioteca.

Tags: c#

Estou tentando fazer a conexão de um WPF com um hardware externo através do usb. Instalei o NuGet HIDSharp e declarei os USB Devices como abaixo:

```
HidDevice _device;
HidStream _deviceStream;
IEnumerable<HidDevice> _deviceList;
```

Isso dentro do `public partial class MainWindow : Window`.
Criei o método `ConnectToUsb` e dentro dele uso `DeviceList` que vem da biblioteca **HidSharp** que foi declarada da seguinte forma `using HidSharp;`

Porém o VS está me reportando um erro no `DeviceList` dizendo que ele não existe naquele contexto, mesmo eu tendo declarado a biblioteca e mesmo o método estando dentro da classe principal. Alguém já passou por isso e teria uma possível solução?

```
private async Task<bool> ConnectToUsb()
        {

            await Task.Delay(1000);
            try
            {
                //manda conectar no dispositivo
                _deviceList = DeviceList.Local.GetHidDevices();
                _device = _deviceList.FirstOrDefault(dev => dev.ProductID == _Pid && dev.VendorID == _Vid && dev.DevicePath.Contains("col01"));
                //inicia o background worker caso encontre
                if (_device != null)
                {
                    //Conecta na placa encontrada
                    _device.Open();
                    if (_device.TryOpen(out _deviceStream))
                    {
                        // TODO Mostrar a capacidade do HID
                        WriteLog($"Placa {cmbBoard.SelectedItem.ToString()} encontrada!", Brushes.Gray);

                        WriteLog("Comunicação estabelecida com sucesso", Brushes.Gray);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Não encontrou nenhum dispositivo
                    // WriteMessage("Erro na Conexão USB!", Brushes.Red);
                    WriteLog("Não foi possível encontrar nenhuma Placa!", Brushes.Red);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao tentar conectar ao dispositivo! " + ex.ToString());
                WriteLog("Erro ao tentar conectar ao dispositivo: " + ex.ToString(), Brushes.Gray);
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Qual é **exatamente** o erro que é apresentado?

Comment: the name 'DeviceList' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: E este `DeviceList` é uma classe/namespace da biblioteca?

Comment: Sim, class HidSharp.DeviceList. Provides a list of all available devices.

Comment: Qual a versão do pacote que você está usando?

Comment: Estou usando a versão 2.0.0-alpha.

Comment: Instalou pelo Nuget? Se sim, tem como postar o conteúdo do arquivo packages.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta classe não está disponível na versão 1.5.0. Que, [segundo esta pergunta anterior, é a versão que você tem referenciada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285249/18246).

Na seção *assembly*, na documentação da classe você pode conferir

> **Namespace**: HidSharp
>   **Assembly**: HidSharp (in HidSharp.dll) Version: 2.0.0-alpha

Você pode instalar esta versão, mas tenha em mente que é uma versão *alpha*. É por sua conta e risco.

Para instalá-la é só usar o comando

> ```
> PM> Install-Package HidSharp -Version 2.0.0-alpha
> ```

Comment: Estava usando a versão 1.5. Quando atualizei a versão para 2.0.0-alpha funcionou, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Pela mensagem de erro:

> the name 'DeviceList' does not exist in the current context.

Creio que talvez o problema seja na sua classe, aonde você chama:

```
 _deviceList = DeviceList.Local.GetHidDevices();
```

Se você tem mais de um script/documento que esta usando HidDevice, então talvez em um deles você tenha esquecido de declarar o `using HidSharp;`, verifique todos documentos que irá usar a classe.

Comment: No início da pergunta ele diz que tem o _statement_ `using HidSharp`

Comment: @LINQ poderia ele ter declarado em um script e em outro não, se ele estiver usando em mais de um arquivo.

Comment: Com certeza. Mas perceba que ele diz que está fazendo tudo na mesma classe (`MainWindow`). Claro que ele pode ser se confundido e escrito errado, só estou me guiando pelo que está escrito na pergunta (e também pelo histórico, onde ele recebe uma resposta que diz para instalar a versão 1.5.0 da biblioteca – versão que não contém a classe citada no erro).

Comment: @LINQ mas pode ser que no MainWindow esteja ok e o console afirmou que o problema é em outro lugar, ele não postou a mensagem inteira, pode ser simplesmente uma confusão, vou aguardar o feedback do AP nisto.